# PromQL Prometheus Query - How do we specify a data range in absolute terms

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

From Grafana Query inspector I am able to get the data for a date range ; Example

`rate(node_disk_read_bytes_total{job="node-exporter",instance="172.18.0.2:9100",device=~"nvme.*"}[20m])`

[image]

I can also give an absolute data time range. When I use the Prometheus GUI to query directly, I am not sure of the syntax of putting the date time range. I know it is in Unix Epoch time

What I have tried in PromQL from reading the docs

`rate(node_disk_read_bytes_total{job="node-exporter",instance="172.18.0.2:9100",device=~"nvme.*"}[10m] @ 1648473649)[1d:10m]`

`1648473649 = Monday, 28 March 2022 13:20:49` https://www.epochconverter.com/

This works, without error and gives data, but the data is wrong (you can see from output it is giving one value all the way 38775.46666666667.

[image]

Also, I would like to give to and from as date timestamps in the above query.

The query which gives proper data in PromQL

`rate(node_disk_read_bytes_total{job="node-exporter",instance="172.18.0.2:9100",device=~"nvme.*"}[10m])[7d:10m]`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

PromQL doesn't allow specifying time range for the query. Instead, the time range is specified via HTTP API args passed to the corresponding endpoints:

- `time` query arg at [/api/v1/query](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#instant-query)
- `start` and `end` query args at [/api/v1/query_range](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#range-query)

Such a design decision allows executing the same PromQL query at any timestamp or on any time range without the need to change the query itself.